# Python - cql - Cassandra 1.2 - rpc timeouts when reading

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I have a Python application using a Cassandra 1.2 cluster. The cluster has 7 physical nodes using virtual nodes, and a replication factor of 3 for 1 of the keyspaces and replication factor of 1 for another. The app uses the cql library to connect to Cassandra and run queries. The problem is that I've started getting errors when trying to run selects on the database, and I get this error:

```
Request did not complete within rpc_timeout
```

When I check the status of the cluster I can see one of my nodes with a cpu usage of over 100% and checking the Cassandra system.log I can see this popping out all the time:

```
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:01,640 StorageService.java (line 3565) Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:02,642 GCInspector.java (line 119) GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 630 ms for 1 collections, 948849672 used; max is 958398464
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:02,643 GCInspector.java (line 142) Heap is 0.9900367202591844 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this automatically
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:02,685 StorageService.java (line 3565) Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:04,224 GCInspector.java (line 119) GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 1222 ms for 2 collections, 931216176 used; max is 958398464
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:04,224 GCInspector.java (line 142) Heap is 0.9716378009554072 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this automatically
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:04,225 StorageService.java (line 3565) Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:05,226 GCInspector.java (line 119) GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 709 ms for 1 collections, 942735576 used; max is 958398464
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:05,227 GCInspector.java (line 142) Heap is 0.9836572275641711 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this automatically
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:05,229 StorageService.java (line 3565) Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:06,946 GCInspector.java (line 119) GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 1271 ms for 2 collections, 939532792 used; max is 958398464
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-06-07 02:02:06,946 GCInspector.java (line 142) Heap is 0.980315419203343 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this automatically
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Cassandra JVM heap size may be too small, only 1Gb:

```
max is 958398464
```

I would suggest increasing the heap to at least 2Gb, assuming you have memory available on your nodes.

See cassandra-env.sh to see how the JVM heap allocation is computed or to manually set it to a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

What type of partitioner do you use and what is your data schema? how many records do you have and how many records your query should return? these are all parameters that we should know to find a correct answer to your question.

I case of Cassandra, data structure design is very important, Cassandra is not like RDBMS databases that you can easily create indexes on every column you want, Cassandra column families must be defined in a way that equally distribute data among cluster nodes to avoid hot spots or reading data only from one cluster node, which I think could be the cause of rpc timeout in your case.

If you need more info please send some more info.
Thanks

I hope this can help you.